# Hardy inequality generalisation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

My understanding is that Hardy's inequality states
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{f^2}{|x|^2}dx \leq \left(\frac{2}{n-2}\right)^2 \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla f|^2dx $$
for $n \geq 3$. I have also seen a Hardy inequality with an additional weight on the LHS and RHS:
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} |x|^p\frac{f^2}{|x|^2}dx \leq \left(\frac{2}{n+p-2}\right)^2 \int_{\mathbb R^n} |x|^p|\nabla f|^2dx. $$
How does one go from the first to the second and, if possible, from the second to the first (with a fixed $p \neq 0$)?

My naive attempt at going from the first to the second would be to start with the sharp inequality without the weight and then replace $f$ with $f|x|^{p/2}$. But the best estimate I can write down is
$$ |\nabla f|x|^{p/2}|^2 \leq 2|\nabla f|^2|x|^p + 2\frac{p^2}{4}f^2|x|^{p-2} $$
by using $|\nabla(fg)|^2 = |g\nabla f + f\nabla g|^2 \leq 2g^2|\nabla f|^2 + 2f^2|\nabla g|^2$.

But this appears to give me a $\int |x|^p\frac{f^2}{|x|^2}dx$ on the RHS with a constant of $(\frac{2}{n-2})^2 \times \frac{p^2}{2}$ and if $p$ is sufficently large while $n$ is held fixed, this is larger than $1$ and it can't be carried over to the LHS. Even if it can be (e.g. $p$ is small) I don't think the constant is correct.

So what is the "correct" way to prove (2) from (1) and conversely (1) from (2)?

Comment: It might be hard to prove the second from the first. But, in fact, we can prove both of them using the more general Hardy's inequality and polar coordinates: if $1\leq p<\infty, r>0$, then $$\int_0^\infty x^{r-1}\left(\int_x^\infty |h(y)|\,dy\right)^p\,dx\leq \left(\frac pr\right)^p\int_0^\infty x^{p+r-1}|h(x)|^p\,dx.$$ This inequality is Exercise 29 in Chapter 6 of Folland's Real Analysis. If you're interested, I can write a detailed proof. Although it doesn't meet your requirment: proving the second using the first.

Comment: Thanks for the reference - I'll leave the question open to see if anyone else is aware of a proof to go from one to to other. But I am wondering, do you happen to know if is it possible to even go from one to the other without the sharp constant? (I suppose what I am saying is whether there is a different substitution or estimate of some sort than what I've written down that makes this approach work at the loss of the sharp constant.)